# Adjust size of "to" box in daterangeInput

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have changed the height of my daterangeInput box but cannot figure out how to get the separator box sized to match.

I used RNotebook to generate the HTML for my code and suspect that this line may hold the key:

to

I tried adding .input-group-addon{height: 22px} - this did not help.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- 
fluidPage(
   tags$style(type='text/css', ".form-control {height: 22px;font-size: 12px;}") 
dateRangeInput('dateRange',label = "Date Range",start = "2009-01-01", end =" 2010-01-01"))                
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOXTc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.input-daterange .input-group-addon {
    height: 22px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
}
```